# Как нарисовать круг радиуса R?

Tags: css3, html, css

Как нарисовать круг радиуса R

1. В пикселях
2. В процентах от ширины и высоты квадратного родительского блока

Comment: @Qwertiy, зачем отмечать этот вопрос как дубликат более нового? Логично было бы провести связь в обратную сторону.

Comment: @mymedia, этот вопрос заброшен, а там ответы лучше.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/po4teda/7jpzq/

```css
#first {
    background-color: red;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border-radius: 32px;
    /* Равен ширине и высоте блока*/
}
#parent {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}
#parent div {
    width: 50%;
    height: calc(50% + 50px);
    /* Иначе JS*/
    height: -moz-calc(50% + 50px);
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="parent">
    <div></div>
</div>
```